# Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer for Php5

Tags: php, pear

Could anyone share the link where I can download Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer for Php5. On the main site http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer I was able to find that it is compatible with php 4.1.0 .. Apparently when i downloaded the code I found a lot of errors which was uncompatible with PHP5 . Could anyone please give me the link where I can download the file which works on PHP5 .
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ ?

Comment: Yes . But in this case I need to change my entire library . i prefer not to do it . So searching a pear package which does the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no php5 port of Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer available on PEAR. Patches welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. You have to ignore a lot of PHP errors, then edit Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer/Worksheet.php and change in line 2490

```
$this->_append(&$string, true);
```

to

```
$string = $this->_append($string, true);
```

and add a line after line 1348 in function _append with

```
return $data;
```

Add the same to Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer/BIFFWriter.php after line 165 in function _append.

Edit: The big issue, however, is in OLE/PPS/Root.php in line 623 you have to change

```
fwrite($FILE, pack("V", 1));
```

to

```
fwrite($FILE, pack("V", $num_sb_blocks));
```